# Dynamically concatenate values into an associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a list of categorized expenses. I'm trying to sum the expenses within each category. I have a solution, but I think I'm adding one extra value. That error might be coming from my loop. However, there's got to be a more elegant way to dynamically add values to an associative array than this:

```
// In a loop, gather this row category and expenses.
$category = $row[$category_key];
$debit = $row[$debit_key];
if (!isset($categorized_expenses[$category])) {
    $categorized_expenses[$category] = $debit;
}
else {
    $categorized_expenses[$category] = $categorized_expenses[$category] + $debit;
}
```

Writing this out I found the error (I wasn't containing the second statement in an `else` block). However, my question still stands, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Which version of php are you using ?

Comment: PHP 7 on - null coalesce ( ?? ) - `$categorized_expenses[$category] = ($categorized_expenses[$category]??0) + $debit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
$category = $row[$category_key];
$debit = $row[$debit_key];
$categorized_expenses[$category] = $categorized_expenses[$category] + $debit;
```